# Calculate Difference of Timestamps

Tags: matlab, datetime, time, timestamp, duration

I want to calculate time difference with the previous line, however, the result is not as expected. For example, the result in `deltatime(2,5)` (see first screenshot) is supposed to be `3` instead of `13` (`17:47-17:44`).

[image]
[image]

My code:

```
% Calculate connection time
sizedate = length(date);

for i=2:sizedate
 X=char(date(i));
 X=[X(1) X(2)];

 if(X=='18')
   timenum_on=char(time(i));
   timenum_b4=char(time(i-1));
     if(timenum_on(5)<timenum_b4(5) || timenum_on(1) >=timenum_b4(1)
        timenum_on(5)=timenum_on(5)+10;
        timenum_on(4)=timenum_on(4)-1;
        deltatime(i,")=timenum_on-timenum_b4;
     else
        timenum_b4(5)=10-timenum_b4(5);
        deltatime(i,:)=timenum_on-timenum_b4;
     end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply subtract/diff the `datetime` objects directly to get [`duration`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html) objects? Here's a demonstration:

```
function out = q48740661
dt = datetime(2017, 02, 12, 17, 43 + (0:4).^2, 12).';
out = flipud(diff(flipud(dt)));
```

```
ans = 

  4×1 duration array

   -0:01:00
   -0:03:00
   -0:05:00
   -0:07:00
```

Comment: Interesting. fyi, the data logs of date and time were imported from excel file into matlab. Is it possible to use datetime object and diff mathematical calculations? Thanks.

Comment: I never tried importing data like that from Excel. I don't understand your follow up question - please clarify. If you are having difficulties with the import process (i.e. the created `datetime` objects don't contain some important information) - you should create a new question specifically about that, and post a small example of the data that can be used to reproduce the problem (save the file as csv then copy-paste into the question). If your question is about doing similar computations in Excel - this, again, should be discussed in the scope of a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating this function:

```
deltatime=func_time(time);
```

Contents of this function:

```
function time_diff= func_time(time_arr)
n=size(time_arr(:,1));
y=n(1);
time_diff=zeros(n,n);
for i=1:y
    for j=1:y
        time_1=time_arr(i,:); %char array of first time
        time_2=time_arr(j,:); %char array of second time
        time_cell=time_1;
        ctr=1;
        for k=1:size(time_1(:)+1)
            if(time_1(k)==':')
                av=str2num(time_1(ctr:(k-1)));
                bv=str2num(time_2(ctr:(k-1)));
                time_cell(ctr:(k-1))=int2str(av-bv)
                ctr=k+1
            end
            if(k==5)
                av=str2num(time_1(ctr:(k)));
                bv=str2num(time_2(ctr:(k)));
                time_cell(ctr:k)=int2str(av-bv)
            end
        end
        time_diff(i,j)=time_cell();
    end
end
```

> Here I am assuming that `deltatime(i,j)` is `time(i)-time(j)`

Comment: n=size(time_arr(:,1)); <-- do u mind to explain this line please.. thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: This is due to the reason that i was running the code on octave online, which was not reading my `time_arr` as a string array, but as a char matrix. 

Still, `size(time_arr)=[a 7]` as the array was 11:22:33 ; 11:23:34 ; ...(a times)
so, `size(time_arr(:,1))=[a 1]` and `y=n(1)=[a]`

**In General,  arr(:,:) means iteration through all rows and columns.**